# Does an Homotopy between local homeos preserve orientation behaviour?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Suppose we have two compact, orientable $n$ manifolds $M,N$, and two **homotopic** local homeos $f,g \colon M \to N$. Suppose moreover that $f$ is orientation preserving.

Is it true that $g$ is orientation preserving?

If the manifolds are not compact it's easy to see a counterexample (the plane and the identity together with the antipodal map), the problems come when we ask compactness. I think that $g$ must be orientation preserving, but I'm unable to prove or disprove it.

I think that my problem is I'm unable to use properly the compactness hypothesis (I know that $H_n(M)=\mathbb{Z}$) but I don't know how to use it)

My definition of orientation is homological, both with local orientations and with sections of the orientation cover.

Comment: You might demand from the homotopy $h:M\times I \to N$ not only that $h(x, 0) = f(x)$ and $h(x, 1) = g(x)$ are local homeomorphisms, but that $h(x, t)$ is a local homeomorphism for all $t \in I$. Then I think the result holds also for non-compact manifolds. (The map you think about in your counterexample would have $h(x, \frac12) = 0$ for all $x$, doesn't it?)

Comment: @Arthur you mean "kind of" isotopy? well in the statement there aren't references to additional properties of the homotopy. Nevertheless, how will your conclusion follows with the additional property?

Comment: I'm not certain that it will, but it does ruin your $\Bbb R^2$-counterexample, so I thought it was worth noting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost by definition, $f : M \to N$ is orientation-preserving iff it sends the fundamental class $[M] \in H_n(M)$ to a *positive* multiple of the fundamental class $[N] \in H_n(N)$. Since homotopic maps induces the same morphism in homology, it follows that $f$ is orientation preserving iff $g$ is.